# vuetify 2 v-data-table nested for loops

Tags: json, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

So I have this:

```
    <div v-for="team in teams" :key="team['.key']">
      <h2>{{ team.teamname }}</h2>
      <div v-for="playerId in team.players" :key="playerId['.key']">
        <p>{{ players[playerId].firstname }}</p>
        <p>{{ players[playerId].lastname }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and I would like to use v-data-table with it instead but I can't make the child data populate. This is the current point of me being stuck:

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="tHeaders"
      :items="Object.values(teams)"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      group-key="team.players.player['.key']"
    >
    </v-data-table>
```

data model is (json):

```
  "players": {
    "p1": {
      ".key": "p1",
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Smith",
      "jerseynumber": 10,
      "teams": {
        "t1": "t1"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    },
    "p2": {
      ".key": "p2",
      "firstname": "Audrey",
      "lastname": "Jones",
      "jerseynumber": 55,
      "teams": {
        "t2": "t2"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    },
    "p3": {
      ".key": "p3",
      "firstname": "Bill",
      "lastname": "Nye",
      "jerseynumber": 40,
      "teams": {
        "t2": "t2"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    },
    "p4": {
      ".key": "p4",
      "firstname": "Grace",
      "lastname": "Dilson",
      "jerseynumber": 30,
      "teams": {
        "t2": "t2"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    },
    "p5": {
      ".key": "p5",
      "firstname": "Ameilia",
      "lastname": "Earhardt",
      "jerseynumber": 11,
      "teams": {
        "t1": "t1"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    },
    "p6": {
      ".key": "p6",
      "firstname": "Ava",
      "lastname": "Sanderson",
      "jerseynumber": 8,
      "teams": {
        "t1": "t1"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    }
  },
  "teams": {
    "t1": {
      ".key": "t1",
      "teamname": "Red Robins",
      "players": {
        "p1": "p1",
        "p5": "p5",
        "p6": "p6"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    },
    "t2": {
      ".key": "t2",
      "teamname": "Blue Unicorns",
      "players": {
        "p2": "p2",
        "p3": "p3",
        "p4": "p4"
      },
      "userId": "u1"
    }
  },
```

I have checked out a few codepens and issues here but they all deal with arrays not objects, and without keys, which may be why I cannot get the child data to display.

Comment: how do you populate your child data?

Comment: I think that might be part of my disconnect. I populate the child data using the non-relational database equivalent of foreign keys. If you look at the player "p1" for example, you'll see that she is on team "t1" which has a teamname of "Red Robins".

Comment: I populate the child data using the non-relational database equivalent of foreign keys. If you look at the player "p1" for example, you'll see that she is on team "t1" which has a teamname of "Red Robins".
In the <div> codeblock I get the child data to populate by using nested for loops. But I can't figure out how to do the same thing with vuetify's v-data-table. It does have a "group-by" option but I haven't had much luck there.
This codepen is a good reference as to what I am going for, but he uses arrays. My data model uses objects. https://codepen.io/lzhoucs/pen/aadaJx